# How to repair multiple KDC an Netlogon errors

Tags: windows-server-2003, netlogon

I have several erros in the system event log of my single Windows 2003 SP2 domain controller.

Multiple member computers on the domain are listed in these errors.
I am seeing two similar errors for each computer one second apart in the event log.

> Event ID 7
>   Source KDC
>   The Security Account Manager failed a
>   KDC request in an unexpected way. The
>   error is in the data field. The
>   account name was MEMBERNAME$@DOMAIN.LOCAL and lookup type
>   0x8.

followed by

> Event ID 7
>   Source KDC
>   The Security Account Manager failed a
>   KDC request in an unexpected way. The
>   error is in the data field. The
>   account name was MEMBERNAME$ and lookup type
>   0x8.

The Lookup Types are also different, I have 0x8, 0x28, 0x0, 0x20.

I am also receiving other authentication errors in the same time frame as all of the KDC errors

> Event ID 5722
>   Source NETLOGON
>   The session setup from the computer
>   MEMBERNAME failed to authenticate. The
>   name(s) of the account(s) referenced
>   in the security database is MEMBERNAME$. 
>   The following error occurred:  Access
>   is denied.

I have run dcdiag /v to see if there was something wrong with Active Directory, but all tests passed.
I also ran netdiag /v and it appers all of those tests ran.

Any ideas on where to start for this issue?

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 1):

> When there are Kerberos problems, it's
>   probably dns. If it's not dns, it's
>   probably dns

*(From Marc Minasi)*

As part of standard checkup, could you check:

- Time. All AD members mustn't have more than 5 minutes difference from DC by default
- dnsdiag: check that all dns zone are replicated
- Do you have enough free space on DC ?
- If you still have Windows 2000 DC/wks, you may check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812499

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to fix errors with PCs that got 5722 error on the DC.
From DC, Event Viewer, System
Error:
    Date: 3/25/13
    Time: 9:06:08 PM
    Source: NETLOGON
    Event ID: 5722
    The session setup from the computer HyperV1 failed to authenticate. The name(s) of the account(s) referenced in the security database is AZSVR-HYPERV1$.  The following error occurred: 
    Access is denied.

How to fix error:
    From Workstation or server that is having the problems.
    Example 
        Server with issue: HyperV1
        Domain: BlueNetowork.local
        Domain Admininistrator User: JSmith
        DC server: BN-DC1

```
Command to run from CMD window open with "Run as Admin..."
Test to make sure it is a "problem computer does not have a valid secure channel established with a domain controller, you receive output that is similar to the following"
    C:\Users\administrator>nltest /sc_query:BlueNetowork.local
    Flags: 0
    Trusted DC Name
    Trusted DC Connection Status Status = 5 0x5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
    The command completed successfully

How to Fix:
    Flush DNS & Arp:
        ipconfig /flushdns
        arp -d *

Restpwd with netdom:
    netdom resetpwd /server:<servername> /userd:<username>\Administrator /passwordd:*
    C:\Users\administrator>netdom resetpwd /server:BN-DC1 /ud:BlueNetowork.local\jsmith /pd:*
    Type the password associated with the domain user:

    The machine account password for the local machine has been successfully reset.

    The command completed successfully.

Test to see if fixed:
    C:\Users\administrator>nltest /sc_verify:BlueNetowork.local
    Flags: b0 HAS_IP  HAS_TIMESERV
    Trusted DC Name \\BN-DC1.BlueNetowork.local
    Trusted DC Connection Status Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
    Trust Verification Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
    The command completed successfully
```